# Debugging Javascript Click handler in Chrome 12

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, event-handling

```
oLink = document.getElementById("ItemDescend");
alert(oLink); // fire up alert with link target
addEventHandler(oLink, "click", function(e) { alert(1); sortTable('theList', 0, true); preventDefault(e); },false); // does not fire up inner alert!
```

This above code functions in all other browsers as tested, but in Chrome 12 does not. I would be grateful if someone shows me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: What is `addEventHandler`? You have to post the implementation, otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: function(oNode, sEvt, fnHandler, bCapture) {
        if (typeof (window.event) != "undefined")
            oNode.attachEvent("on" + sEvt, fnHandler);
        else
            oNode.addEventListener(sEvt, fnHandler, bCapture);
    },

Comment: That is because Chrome does have `window.event`, but it does not have `attachEvent`. It would be better to check if oNode has `attachEvent` defined. Even better, use a framework that abstracts these details away.

Comment: But on window load event this function is working.. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addEventHandler` method is checking for an unrelated property, which is wrong.

Instead, you should check for the `addEventListener` method, and only call `attachEvent` if that doesn't exist.
Change the condition to

```
if (typeof (oNode.addEventListener) !== "function")
```

Comment: It is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nqmJf/   you may have a typo or some other issue.

Comment: *addEventListener* is a host method and may not return *function* when tested with *typeof* (e.g. in IE, methods implemented using ActiveX return "unknown"), so probably better to use `if (oNode.addEventListener)`.

Comment: I am getting [Object HTMLDivElement] in jsfiddle.net/nqmJf, not 1. And would suggest you to make that div a link, just in case... I didnt try it...

Comment: @Rob: I was wondering about that.  I had hoped that that was fixed by IE9, which is the only version with `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Dejan: If you click `fooooo` in his demo, you'll get `1`.

Comment: Just try it out again and in my speed I did mess something up! It is working fully. Thanks.

Comment: @SLaks - IE may also return "object" and "other" for methods of host objects.  I think the general rule is: don't depend on host objects implementing features of ECMAScript, code to the lowest common denominator (well, IE 6 and higher at least) :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
addEventHandler(obj,type,fn)
{
    if(obj.addEventListener)
    {
        obj.addEventListener(type,fn,false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent)
    {
        obj.attachEvent("on"+type,fn);
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that when called, the listener's *this* will be set differently depending on which method was used to add it.